# What is push-pull cooling?

Tags: cooling, hardware-rec

I was reading review site that said the best option to setup a liquid cooling system (Corsair h100) would be to use a push-pull configuration.

What does this mean?

My guess was

> *air pulled from system from fan* > *radiator* > *another fan attached to the other side of the radiator pushes air out*

Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct. The corsair blog has a good post on this topic with the following image being a part of [that post](http://blog.corsair.com/?p=987). The H100 will work in the same fashion. I use a H60 with push-pull to aid the radiator in dispersing the heat. Youtube also has a bunch of videos showing the [H100 in push-pull configuration.](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=H100%20push%20pull&aq=f)

[image]